# Equating two 2D dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: arrays, c, scope, malloc

I have a problem with a for loop in this function that takes a matrix "a", replaces the first column with a vector "b" obtaining a new matrix "aa" and does a calculation with "aa", then repeats the instructions for the other columns (in short, it gives solution to a linear system of equations):

```
double* solution(double** a, double* b, int n, double detA)
{
    double* sol = (double*)malloc((n) * sizeof(double));
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
        {
            double** aa = a;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                aa[i][k] = b[i];
            }
            sol[k] = (determinant(aa, n)) / detA;
        }
    }
    return sol;
}
```

The line `double** aa = a;` correctly create a matrix "aa" equal to "a" and the first run of the external for loop (k=0 case) also gives the correct first solution "sol[0]".
The problem is that when the for loop with k=1 begins, it does not create a new matrix "aa" equal to "a", but it uses the same matrix with the first column substituted. So at the end I have a matrix with all the columns equal to "b".

All the rest of the code works fine. The problem is exactly here. I thought that when the new matrix "aa" was created INSIDE the for loop it was destroyed at the end of EACH loop and a new one was created at the beginning of each loop.

What should I do? I may write a longer code to make sure the matrix is created exactly as I want but I prefer something like the code i wrote.

Comment: `double** aa = a;` *never* created a new matrix; it *literally* makes `aa` point to the same thing that `a` did.

Comment: Ooooh sure! So the only way to make what I had in mind is to create a new matrix and equate every component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your "array" is an array of pointers to pointers to `double`, then you need to allocate new one on every iteration:

```
double **arraydup(double **a, size_t n)
{
    double** aa = malloc(n * sizeof(*aa));
    if(aa)
    {
        for(size_t index = 0; index < n; index++)
        {
            aa[index] = malloc(n * sizeof(**aa));
            if(aa[index])
            {
                memcpy(aa[index], a[index], n * sizeof(**aa));
            }
            else
            {
                for(size_t freeIndex = 0; freeIndex < index; freeIndex++)
                    free(aa[index]);
                free(aa);
                aa = NULL;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return aa;
}

void freeArr(double **a, size_t n)
{
    if(a)
    {
        for(size_t index = 0; index < n; index++)
        {
            free(a[index]);
        }
        free(a);
    }
}



double* solution(double** a, double* b, size_t n, double detA)
{
    double* sol = malloc(n * sizeof(*sol));
    if(sol)
    {
        for (size_t k = 0; k < n; k++)
        {
            double** aa = arraydup(a, n);
            if(!aa) 
            {
                free(sol);
                sol = NULL;
                break;
            }
            for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                aa[i][k] = b[i];
            }
            sol[k] = (determinant(aa, n)) / detA;
            freeArr(aa, n)
        }
    }
    return sol;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply, gulpr. It seems a little bit longer for me however :D

After the reply by Scott Hunter I adjusted the code in this way:

```
double* solution(double** a, double* b, int n, double detA)
{
    double* sol = (double*)malloc((n) * sizeof(double));
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
    {
            double** aa = createMatrix(n);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    aa[i][j] = a[i][j];
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                aa[i][k] = b[i];
            }
            sol[k] = (determinant(aa, n)) / detA;
    }
    return sol;
}
```

Comment: you forgot to free temporary matrix

Comment: you also do not check for memory allocation errors

Comment: and also don't cast result of malloc

Comment: Surely, it would be more efficient to save just the column you're replacing with b, then restore it afterwards rather than copying the whole matrix.

Comment: Sorry, so the allocated memory remains until the program stops? I think I must free all the matrices previouslt created in the rest of the code.

Comment: Instead I intentionally do not check for memory allocation errors. I know I should do it but this is only one of the first excercises in C++

Comment: Sorry again but I don't understand what you mean with "and also don't cast result of malloc".

Comment: If this is C++ prefer new and delete over malloc and free.